# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 why?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

```
USE Airline;

CREATE TABLE Responsible_for(
Time_work TIME NOT NULL,
date_work DATE NOT NULL,
Staff_ID INT NOT NULL,
Passenger_ID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(Passenger_ID) REFERENCES Passenger(Passenger_ID),
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(Staff_ID) REFERENCES Staff(Staff_ID));

SELECT * FROM airline.Responsible_for;
INSERT INTO  Responsible_for VALUES(
    ('04:00:00','2019-04-01',1235,'1102546778'));
```

why there is error? 
thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have an additional pair of parentheses around the list of values that should not be there.

That should be:

```
INSERT INTO Responsible_for(time_work, date_work, staff_id, passenger_id) 
VALUES ('04:00:00','2019-04-01',1235,'1102546778');
```

Notes:

- it is a good practice to always enumerate the columns to `insert`; this prevents hard-to-debug issues, and can make the code resilient to changes in the structure of the target table
- you `use airline` at the beginning of the script, so there is no need to prefix the table name with the schema name in the `insert` statement
- I would recommend against storing the date and time components in separate columns; this makes things unnecessarily complicated (and less efficient) when you need to compare it against a datetime; MySQL has the `datetime` datatype, that is meant to store both together